# fail2ban for apache access log

Tags: apache-2.2, fail2ban

I have tried all the approaches I know of to get the host from the apache access log but none have worked

my basic testing approach is as follows:

```
fail2ban-regex '87.97.244.57 - - [05/Nov/2015:12:46:24 -0500] "GET /index.php/?a=30%60%22( HTTP/1.1" 200 22639 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)' '^<HOST> - - [[^]+] ".*60.20.*'
```

I have tried `^<HOST> - - [[^]+] ".*60.20.*` `<HOST> - - [[^]+] ".*60.20.*` `[[]client []].*60.20.*` `^<HOST>.*60.20.*$` `.*60.20.*` ... etc.

They either miss the target line or I get an error `fail2ban.server.failregex.RegexException: No 'host' group in [...]`

Answer (score 2):

It's really difficult to understand what you're trying to do, to match the host it's as simple as

```
'^<host>'
```

If you want to match more specific things then

```
'^<host> - - .*30%60%22'
```

works.

The error message you have been getting is because the `(` is being interpreted as part of a regex grouping which you leave unterminated. you should escape it like this

```
'^<host> - - .*30%60%22\('
```

Comment: the `(` is never part of the regex.

Comment: it's actually because I'm an idiot and I was doing 60.20 instead of 60.22... sorry